# Javascript toggle list-style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a little toggle switch which removes line numbers on click.

I have got it working here: http://www.webdevout.net/test?09&raw

It is code highlighted by Geshi, and i build the javascript at the top to toggle line numbers.

This works fine, but what I would really want is that when the line numbers are 'hidden', that it also removes that gap on the left. So that the actual code fills the screen.

If clicked again, the lines numbers would come back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `ol` element's padding to 0:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].style.padding = '0';
```

Above script is assuming you only have one `<ol>` in your document, or at least the first one is the one you'd like to edit.

**EDIT**

You would have to switch between

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].style.paddingLeft = '20px';
```

and

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].style.paddingLeft = '0px';
```

Your approach is a tad bit wrong though, you should be changing the listStyle of the `<ol>` tag and not of the individual `<li>` tags.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].style.listStyle = 'none';
```

and

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].style.listStyle = 'decimal';
```

**EDIT2** Perhaps give this a try. If you could also link me to it, I can test it in chrome and firefox as well. Maybe I'm not getting your problem..

```
function toggle_visibility() {
     var e = document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0];
     if(e.style.listStyle == 'none') {
       e.style.listStyle = 'decimal';
       e.style.paddingLeft = '20px';
     } else {
       e.style.listStyle = 'none';
       e.style.paddingLeft = '0px';
     }
  }
}
```

Link

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility();">toggle</a>
```

**EDIT3**

Ah, I found the problem :)

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].style.listStyle.substr(0,4) == 'none')
```

Because when you set the listStyle to 'none' it actually gets set to 'none outside none' by firefox and IE. So if you use .substr(0,4) to get the first 4 characters to compare to none, you should be fine :)

Comment: Awesome Rick, that worked like a charm! One issue I still have is with firefox. In chrome it works fine, but in Firefox I can 'hide' the line, but when i click it again, they do not come back. Any ideas?

Comment: The last example does not actually hide the space on the left, but PaddingLeft to 0 does. But it still doesn't untoggle in Firefox and IE, chrome works fine.

Comment: That last one didn't work :( , but my original code a lot smaller using your suggestions. http://pastebin.com/EfRwUj4U this works great in Chrome, but still won't untoggle in IE and FF.